# If an XSD does not provide explicitly what encoding should be used, then what encoding should be used by default?

Tags: xml, xsd

I have an XSD schema but it does not explicitly state what encoding scheme should be used. What is considered the default character encoding when the XSD does explicitly detail which scheme is to be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you talking about the encoding of the schema documents or the encoding of the instance documents?

For schema documents, they are the same as any other XML document: the default encoding is UTF-8, unless out-of-band information is available that indicates otherwise.

For instance documents: the schema has nothing to say about the encoding of instance documents. A schema is used to validate an Infoset, and infosets do not have an encoding; encoding differences are dealt with in the process of creating an Infoset from a source XML document (the process usually called "parsing").